# why getServerSideProps(SSR) doesn't work at vercel deploy

Tags: next.js, google-signin, server-side-rendering, vercel

I am trying to deploying next js instagram clone coding.
so i used the getServerSideProps for singin with google.
it works at localhost:3000 what i want.
but after deploying this web then when i click the signin then turns out server error page.

i don't know what can i do to solve this problem.

i already downgrade firbase to 9.4.0
and i used getStaticProps(?) instead of getServerSideProps..

(if i need to use useeffect instead of getServerSideProps then please show me detail code please.... i am beginner :( )
please help me out

this is signIn code:

```
import {getProviders, signIn as SignIntoProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import Image from "next/future/image";
//Brower...
function signIn({providers}){
    return (
        <>
        <Header />

        <div className="flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen py-2 mt-56 text-center">
            <Image className="w-80" src="/img/스쿼드 로고.png" alt="" width={400} height={200}/>

            <p className="font-xs italic">
                SQUARD PROJECT - By EunSeo PARK  
            </p>
                <div className='mt-20'>
                    {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                        <div key={provider.name}>
                            <button className="p-3 bg-blue-500 rounded-lg text-white" onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id, {callbackUrl: "/"})}>
                                Sign in with {provider.name}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
        </div>
    </>
    );
}

//Server side 
//export async function getServerSidedProps
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders();

    if (!providers) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            providers,
        },
    };

}

export default signIn;
```

this is the package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.5.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "fake": "^0.2.2",
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.10.3",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.6.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "recoil": "^0.7.5",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^2.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

this is the next.config.js code:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost', 'images.unsplash.com', 'googleusercontent.com','lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'firebasestorage.googleapis.com', 'googleapis.com','cloudflare-ipfs.com']
    
  },
  
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        sky: colors.sky,
        cyan: colors.cyan,
      },
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: _"when i click the signin then turns out server error page"_ - What is the server error? You can check server logs under [Function Logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs) in Vercel.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?